# Displaying both father and son in a RESTful API?

Tags: django, rest

I'm trying to use the Django REST framework to generate json I'll be able to use later on my website. The thing is, I have Users, who have one-to-many projects, and these projects have one-to-many tasks.

The thing is, I'd like to display a list of my users, then when I access the details of an user, I can see his projects. Then, when I check the details of a project, I can see the tasks of this project. Now, my models are defined like this :

```
class SimpleUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    firstname = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.TextField(max_length=40)

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(SimpleUser, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=255)

class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='task_project')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

And when I'm trying to display for example the Projects linked to an User, I have an error no matter what I try (I'm pretty sure this is because what I do is wrong), and the error is "SimpleUser has no attribute Project". Which is logical. But I really don't know how to do this, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `project_set` to access `SimpleUsers` `Projects`.

```
user = SimpleUser.objects.get(id=1)
projects = user.project_set.all()
```

Or define a specific name for the manager with `related_name=`:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(SimpleUser, null=True, related_name='projects')
```

Then you can access users projects via `projects`:

```
projects = user.projects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying explicitly the `related_name` for the relationship:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(SimpleUser, null=True, related_name='projects')
    name = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```